# Dataframe_Filter the two columns/Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to filter the datatable Column C contains and, with column b is empty

Example :
Df1

```
   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
    1               and 
    2       note    and
    3               or
    4               and
```

result
df2

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1               and
4               and
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are working with pandas dataframe. If this is the case, then you can do `Df1.loc[(Df1['ColumnB'].isnull()) & (Df1['ColumnC'] == 'and')]`

If your "empty" cell means blank-space, i.e., `""`; then you should do `Df1.loc[(Df1['ColumnB'] == "") & (Df1['ColumnC'] == 'and')]`